# How to get objects from a JSON array?

Tags: android, arrays, json

From this JSON array, I have to obtain the values `Q8` and `89`? How to get it?

```
[{
    "Policy_Id": "199",
    "Status_Eng": "Approved",
    "INFO": [
        {
            "Caption": "Chs No",
            "Val": "Q8"
        },
        {
            "Caption": "Reg No",
            "Val": "89"
        },
        {
            "Caption": "Year",
            "Val": "06"
        },
        {
            "Caption": "Me",
            "Val": "hun"
        },
        {
            "Caption": "Mol",
            "Val": "hhh"
        }
    ]
}]
```

My current code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jboj = array.getJSONObject(i);
    para = new Quote();
    para.pol_status = jboj.getString("Status_Eng");

    JSONArray array1 = jboj.getJSONArray("INFO");

    for (int j = 0; j < array1.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject jObj1 = array1.getJSONObject(j);
        para.cnum = jObj1.getString("Val").toString();
        para.cnum = jObj1.getString("Val").toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the JSON is valid, it looks like this (after the edit). If it's not, then OP should fix it, to look like this.

Answer (score 1):

Saving all the values to a list

```
List<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jboj = array.getJSONObject(i);
    para = new Quote();
    para.pol_status = jboj.getString("Status_Eng");

    JSONArray array1 = jboj.getJSONArray("INFO");

    for (int j = 0; j < array1.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject jObj1 = array1.getJSONObject(j);
        listOfValues.add(jObj1.getString("Val");
    }
}
```

If you want the specific q8 then it is `listOfValues.get(0)`

Comment: there a lot of values ..i have shortened the JSON...ie there are many more arrays..

Comment: Then you should update the question so that it reflects that you want a list of all the "Val" values...

Answer (score 0):

Now that the JSON is fixed, the code you have posted should work fine:

```
for (int j = 0; j < array1.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject jObj1 = array1.getJSONObject(j);
    para.cnum = jObj1.getString("Val").toString();
}
```

This should get all the values of the `Val` fields. If you do not need all of them, you can simply check them in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);


JSONArray infoArray = object.getJSONArray("INFO");
JSONObject objectZero = infoArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject objectOne = infoArray.getJSONObject(1);
String valQ8 = objectZero.getString("Val");
String _89 = objectOne.getString("Val");
```

Answer (score -1):

try below code get String info as

```
    String info = jboj.getString("INFO");

    JSONArray infoArray = new JSONArray(info);

  for (int infoIndex = 0; infoIndex < infoArray.length();infoIndex++)
                    {

                    JSONObject infoObj = infoArray.getJSONObject(infoIndex );


                        // read the properties here

                        }
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all send Synchronous request .. 
by looking at your given array..there is dictionary INFO..
NSURLResponse* response = nil;

```
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:nil];

NSDictionary *dictResp = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];


dictResp=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

NSArray * arrProjectDetails =[dictResp objectForKey:@"INFO"];

this array will contain all values of "Caption" and "val"..
you can get it using index of array ..

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not Java. This is not an Objective-C question.